# Not able to run inbuilt Maps Activity and Navigation Activity on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-maps

I am behind a proxy. So I made the proxy settings and I'm able to access the internet from a browser. But the Maps Activity does not load. I get this error:

```
Wrong remote strings version. GMM Server must be hosting: /strings_remote_533149424.dat
```

I'm doing this because I tried using Google Map APIs but all I got was a grey grid with no map. So I just wanted to test whether the GPS on the emulator is working or not.

Answer (score 2):

[Solved]
The GPS on Android Emulator doesn't work behind a proxy. When I switched over direct Internet connection - it works.